# how to shift the downarrows toward little bit right side?

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

How to draw the following diagram in Tikz-pgf?

Also in the current code, how to shift the downarrows toward little bit right side. I want the downarrows just down A and above A'  and  the function f_1 at the right or left and so on for others. In the current graph the downarrows are placed toward little bit left side.

[image]

I have used the following code to get above graph:

```
\begin{align}
\matrix{
A&\longrightarrow&B &\longrightarrow&C&\longrightarrow&D&\longrightarrow&E
\cr \downarrow f_1&&\downarrow f_2&&\downarrow f_3&&\downarrow f_4&& \downarrow f_5
\cr A' &\longrightarrow&B'&\longrightarrow& C' &\longrightarrow& D'&\longrightarrow&E'}
\end{align}
```

Please help me to fix the above code without using Tikz-CD

Comment: Better is to use tikz-cd` package than pure `tikz` and its `matrix` library.

Comment: @Zarko, can you leave a answer please in `tikz-cd`?

Comment: Done! See answer below.

Comment: @Zarko, I tried but couldn't  add `Tikz-CD` through MikTex Admin update.It is asking local repository file and I am selecting the Tikz-CD file where I kept it, but is saying, not found. That is why I thought to keep the above code of mine. But I need to fix the `downarrows` to make straight connection between the up and down objects and to place the maps `f_i` to the right or left as in your picture. Can you help to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, baseline=3ex]
A \ar[r] 
  \ar[d,"f_1"] & B \ar[r] 
                   \ar[d,"f_2"] & C \ar[r] 
                                    \ar[d,"f_3"] & D \ar[r] 
                                                     \ar[d,"f_4"] & E \ar[d,"f_5"]   \\
A' \ar[r]     & B' \ar[r]       & C' \ar[r]      & D' \ar[r]      & E'               \\
\end{tikzcd}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

for details of `tikz-cd`, which is based on TikZ `matrix` library, see its documentation. It is part of your LaTeX installation or you can find on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd?lang=en) .

*Edit*: Corrected is error in functions indices

Comment: Thanks. Beautiful.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, you are welcome. Now I see, thatI I forgot on prime symbols in the second row of diagram Corrected now.

Comment: I think my Latex editor has no such package.It is saying `i do not know '/tikz/r'`,  You provided a link. I downloaded it. Can you tell me how to implement it with my latex editor  ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKA, editor haven't any package, they are part of your LaTeX installation. Check if `tikz-cd` is installed or simple use vizard of your LaTeX installation and load it. Which LaTeX distribution you use=

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Zarko Hi...there is a fix typo in your code. There are two f_3.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you are right ... apparently I employ copy-past dwarf ;-). I will corrected ASAP

Answer (score 3):

Surely also with `xy` package it is possible to realize your desidered output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2.5pc{
A \ar[d]^{f_1} \ar[r] & B \ar[d]^{f_2}  \ar[r] &  C \ar[d]^{f_3} \ar[r]  & D \ar[d]^{f_4} \ar[r] & E \ar[d]^{f_5}\\
A' \ar[r] & B'  \ar[r] & C'  \ar[r] & D' \ar[r] & E'}

\xymatrix@R=2.5pc@C=2.5pc{
A \ar[d]^{f_1} \ar[r] & B \ar[d]^{f_2}  \ar[r] &  C \ar[d]^{f_3} \ar[r]  & D \ar[d]^{f_4} \ar[r] & E \ar[d]^{f_5}\\
A' \ar[r] & B'  \ar[r] & C'  \ar[r] & D' \ar[r] & E'}

\end{document}
```

PS: With `@R=2.5pc@C=2.5pc` (`R`=row; `C`=column) you can change the dimension of the matrix.

Comment: +1: Looks good!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you so much from the bottom of my heart....

Comment: @Sebastiano, It is really a nice answer. It worked fine in latex editor. Thanks

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR :-)) Thank you very much for your feedback.